# How i can take the differece between two timings in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i need to show a label in the tableview as Xseconds ago and xminutes&yseconds ago,X hrs ago like that.i am doing like this `

```
NSString *todaysdateString=[dict objectForKey:@"sendingtime"];

NSString *time = todaysdateString;
NSString*todaysdateString1=[NSString stringWithString: @" "];

NSDate *date1;
NSDate *date2;
//{
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
date1 = [formatter dateFromString:time];
date2 = [formatter dateFromString:[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
[formatter release];
//}
NSTimeInterval interval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate: date2];
float seconds = interval;
float hour = interval / 3600;
float minute =(interval - hour*3600) / 60;
NSLog(@"%02.0f,%02.0f,%02.0f",hour, minute, seconds);
```

`But this wont giving me the desired answers,I am getting like -0,00,-297 that is utterly wrong.Can anybody point me in where i am going wrong..

Comment: what's value you are having for date1, date2 and interval?

Comment: just go through the code....pls date1 = [formatter dateFromString:time];

Comment: i wanted to know after his acutall passed date and after formatter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your seconds is in negative, you should swap your date here

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate: date2];
```

to :

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate: date1];
```

And can do as :

```
NSInteger intervalInt=interval;

NSInteger seconds = intervalInt % 60;
NSInteger minutes = (intervalInt / 60) % 60;
NSInteger hours = intervalInt / (60 * 60);
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

Comment: what needs to be  date3 here?

Comment: Sorry date1, as mentioned swap(1 with 2), it got typo :p

Comment: u have written as interval%60 that will give u “invalid operands to binary expression” as interval type is different.thats wat i meant ,i hope u understoood

Comment: ohh shitt... i only compiled and forgot NSInterval gives double and % works with integers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `NSCalendar` to do this, maybe this code helps you

```
NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                    fromDate:initialDate
                                      toDate:endDate
                                     options:0];
```

and in the `components` variables you will have the differences, get it back using: `components.day`, `components.minute` and `components.second`